# MySQL и заглавная "И"

Tags: mysql, sql

Работаю с MySQL таблицей, для всей таблицы при создании указано `CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin`. Кириллица обрабатывается вся успешно, за исключением заглавной "И".

```
mysql> select count(*) from bashorg where rstr="Гы";
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from bashorg where rstr="Иа";
ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_bin,IMPLICIT) and (cp1251_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
mysql> select count(*) from bashorg where rstr="И";
ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_bin,IMPLICIT) and (cp1251_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
```

Откуда такая дискриминаия в отношении одной бувы "И"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, что на сервере установлена кодировка соединений "cp1251".

Для исправления ошибки можно либо изменить конфигурацию сервера, либо в начале каждой сессии выполнять

```
set character set utf8mb4;
```